# How to add custom directive name to element using angular or jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to add custom directive name to an element like we add attribute name and their values using `attr()` method in jquery .

For example supoose I have a custom directive named **example-directive** and I want to call this directive on an element programmatically like in the following js fiddle example I want to add **example-directive** on the **div** that has **ID** **sam**.

Could anyone tell me how to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/383/

Answer (score 1):

You were so close to do it. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ge87pgnf/) is the fiddler that is doing it and [here](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/passing-configuration-params-using-html-attributes.html) is an article that explains it in more detail.

You've missed:

```
console.log(attrs['exampleDirective1']);
```

Edit:

As per your comment you can add the attribute with jQuery like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zhwptu1g/) also you can find the docummentation for .attr [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: I want to add directive name to the Div that contains Id "sam" . 
Like in following example on button click I can add attribute name on element using jauery attr() . Same way I want to add Directive name on div element that has id "sam" on button click.

http://jsfiddle.net/ge87pgnf/2/

Comment: In other words you want to use your `exampleDirective1` on the div that has `id=sam` ?

Comment: @angle-bracket please look on my edit. it should do the trick. you can see the id with firebug or some inspecting tools

Answer (score 0):

[$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) is the key here. Assuming that you actually want to replace that div with the directive of yours. You need to find that element and then compile your directive html and replace it with that. Without compile it will not work and you'd just see the html.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $element, $compile) {
    var element = $element.find("#sam");
    var compiled = $compile('<div example-directive1>{{message}}</div>')($scope);
    element.replaceWith(compiled);
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/384/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the attribute of the element using JQuery

   `$('#id').attr('directive-name', '1');`
2. Compile the attribute

   `$compile($('#id'))($scope);`

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmgu56v8/)